# Simulate local run for cron job

Tags: python, cron

1) I have a script (calling python), that runs perfectly on local

2) The same scripts crashes on `cron`

3) I know it's related to environment as: `env <my script>` reproduces the error exactly

4) I have no `.bash`, `.profile` or any of those common files. They do not exist but its clear the `env` is setup somehow.

I tried `printenv` and tried to copy-paste into my script, it didnt work.

Any ideas into where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to troubleshoot cron is to redirect the stdout and stderr to a log file

```
5 * * * * path_to_yourscript > /tmp/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Let cron run and then take a look at the log file

Comment: As I pointed out, on my step 3), I can easily reproduce the issue without the need of cron, `env` simulates an empty environment and it crashes the script

Comment: What is the error ? Have you tried adding "bash -x" to the beginning of the script to provide some additional details ?

Comment: The issue is very specific to the code running, it complains about unable to parse unicode strings, but I feel some other sub-process is breaking. The code belongs to other team, I am just working on the automation of it. The bash is just calling `python something.py` with some pre-defined arguments